# Is Krishna (or Vishnu) also called as Kaamshantak?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, krishna, kama, kamadeva

Is Krishna also called as Kaamshantak ? Or Is it the name of Vishnu ?

If not who is called as Kaamshantak (somone who pacifies lust ) ?

I think Shiva is the one who killed Kamadev once.
Also Kamdev in his human avatar is son of Krishna.

The title Kaamshantak is being addressed to Krishna in one of [Kailsh Kher song.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ib1eHdjjPwg)  What is the source for it ?
(Lyrics are provided in description)

Comment: Okay this is funny. He means Kamsantaka or killer of Kamsa. He has mispronounced it